# Question is actually answer

Tags: support

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324474/asp-net-mvc-microsoftmvcajax-js-throws-javascript-error-when-updating-table-el) is actually the *answer* to a question like "why does MicrosoftMvcAjax.js throw an unknown runtime error in IE8 or older".

I have not been able to find/google any discussion or other answers specific to this question, or a fix for it apart from what is in the linked question.

I wonder if someone (a mod?) can;

1. Re-open this question (to stop it from possibly being deleted by a
   clean-up) and;
2. Convert it into the correct question/answer format

It would be a shame to lose this excellent fix due to the author's formatting

Comment: You or someone else will have to post an answer. Not a mod function to convert questions that answer themselves in twain

Answer (score 5):

Fixed.  But anyone with 2K reputation can do the same thing I did.

Comment: thanks, I only have 1k rep.  Is there any risk of deletion of the question because its [closed]?

Comment: Yes, but it stayed on the site for ages after it was closed the first time.

Comment: ah, i didn't realise it was a 2nd closure.  Oh well, I tried :)